# Possible to access htaccess via Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I don't have cpanel, domain, or hosting access for a client's website, but need htaccess.

Is this possible or do I need more access to get into htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have wp-admin access and can use the theme editor or install plugins, you have essentially the ability to run any PHP code that you wish to run. Whether you are able to write to the .htaccess depends on whether the user that PHP is executed as is allowed to write it, but in most cases: yes, you can.

There are also plugins just for that purpose, to edit the .htaccess from the WP backend.

Be aware (and extra careful) that you might, for all intents and purposes, kill the site if you edit it and create parsing errors, as it will be read & interpreted on every request, so you won't be able to change it back if you've introduced a syntax error.

Comment: I have a wpress file back up & the hosting provider has a full backup. If I make an error, will either back restore the site?

Comment: You won't be able to because you don't have access in that case (unless you get FTP/cpanel access). Whether the hosting provider will (be able/willing to) you'll have to ask them. Most I've come in contact with haven't been willing to, because their backups are meant for mistakes on their end, not yours, and depending on the setup, somebody from their staff might have to manually do it.